# How to verify phone number using OTP without Authentication in Flutter

Tags: flutter, phone-number

How to implement phone number verification in Flutter. In my app user is signed in via email, after the sign in process i need to add the phone number and verify it via OTP. I tried in Firebase the phone number verification is added with the authentication flow.

I don’t want to include the authentication flow, i just need to verify the number. How to implement this?

Please someone help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to implement phone number verification without using Firebase Authentication as phone number verification is a feature within the Firebase Authentication system.

Comment: Can you suggest any other method to achieve this without Firebase.

Comment: you can consider using a third-party service such as Twilio or Nexmo, which provide APIs for voice calls and SMS verification.

Comment: Thanks for help @HoRiZ. i will check the third party service.